# Linq to XML query to SQL

Tags: sql, linq, coldfusion

## UPDATE:

I've turned my xml into a query table in coldfusion, so this may help to solve this.

So my data is:

```
[id] | [code] | [desc] | [supplier] | [name] | [price]
------------------------------------------------------
1    | ABCDEF | "Tst0" |   "XYZ"    | "Test" | 123.00
2    | ABCDXY | "Tst1" |   "XYZ"    | "Test" | 130.00
3    | DCBAZY | "Tst2" |   "XYZ"    | "Tst2" | 150.00
```

Now what I need is what the linq to xml query outputs below. Output should be something like (i'll write it in JSON so it's easier for me to type) this:

```
[{
    "code": "ABCD", 
    "name": "Test", 
    "products": 
        {
            "id": 1,
            "code": "ABCDEF",
            "desc": "Tst0",
            "price": 123.00
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "code": "ABCDXY",
            "desc": "Tst1",
            "price": 130.00
        }
},
{
    "code": "DCBA", 
    "name": "Tst2", 
    "products": 
        {
            "id": 3,
            "code": "DCBAZY",
            "desc": "Tst2",
            "price": 150.00
        }
}]
```

As you can see, Group by the first 4 characters of 'CODE' and 'Supplier' code.

Thanks

---

How would i convert the following LINQ to XML query to SQL?

```
from q in query
group q by new { Code = q.code.Substring(0, 4), Supplier = q.supplier } into g
select new
{
  code = g.Key.Code,
  fullcode = g.FirstOrDefault().code,
  supplier = g.Key.Supplier,
  name = g.FirstOrDefault().name,
  products = g.Select(x => new Product { id = x.id, c = x.code, desc = string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.desc) ? "Description" : x.desc, price = x.price })
}
```

Best i could come up with:

```
SELECT c, supplier, n
FROM products
GROUP BY C, supplier, n
```

Not sure how to get the subquery in there or get the substring of code.

ps: this is for coldfusion, so I guess their version of sql might be different to ms sql..

Comment: What's nice about LINQ, it's an higher abstraction level and make it easier to do things that are much harder to do in SQL.

Comment: Just attach a SQL profiler and see what SQL query gets executed.

Comment: the query is actually LINQ to XML, not from a database..

Comment: Looks like you misunderstood what LINQ is. LINQ is a generic query language over some provider. LINQ to XML will generate XPath queries. Linq to NHibernate or EF will generate SQL. It's up to the provider to generate the appropriate query. XPath is as different from SQL as XML is from an entire RDBMS system. What makes a good XPath query is almost certainly a horrible SQL query.

Comment: @rudeovskizebear I suppose you can't return products in that way. In Linq it would be a collection, in sql - it is a table. But in SQL you can't select a table in your subquery, only a single value. So, I suppose you should try to make two select queries - one is for products, second - is for the results of the first one.

Comment: I've added an update to my code.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to attache a profiler to you database and see what query is generate by the linq-to-SQL engine.